# spring ajax request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring 3.1 web application and am trying to make an ajax request, but in firebug I can see my mapping isn't found. I tried various things, but am not able to just reach my controller method. Here are some details:

this I have i my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ctrl/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this I have in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ctrl/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String test() {
    System.out.println("method test()");
    return "aString";
}
```

this I have in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have another request mapped to a method in my controller and that one is working, but it's not ajax:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ctrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    initializeTree(session);
    return "tree";
}
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ctrl/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("method test()");
    return null;
}
```

On the client side, I use jQuery:

```
$.get(
     "ctrl/test/",
     function(data){
         alert(data);
});
```

I can build on this; my System.out.println is getting printed, so I can reach my controller now

Answer (score 2):

I'm always using ajax based links as *.action or *.ajax for AJAX based requests and *.html mapping for jsp views. Then your dispatcher Servlet should be the following

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ajax</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

next Step:

if all your ajax commands URI starts with /ctrl I recommend you the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/ctrl")
public class AjaxController{

@RequestMapping(value="/test.ajax", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String test(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("method test()");
    return "test";

}
}
```

Don't Forget to add `@ResponseBody` annotation to your ajax based mapping.

now your view controller for index.html should be the following:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController{

@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("method test()");
    return "index";

}
}
```

Comment: thx for the tips; I like the extension for ajax based requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet is not mapped for `/ctrl/test`, so it won't get invoked for the AJAX controller.

Change your `servlet-mapping` to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ctrl/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So that the dispatcher can dispatch both URLs.

For more info, this may help (Weblogic specific but applies in general): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/components.html#148787

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I tried your suggestion. I can see following urls are being mapped when starting up JBoss: [/ctrl/test], [/ctrl/test.*], [/ctrl/test/], [/ctrl], [/ctrl.*] and [/ctrl/]. But I still cannot reach my handler method (public @ResponseBody String test()).

Comment: Is your AJAX controller sending GETs or is it possible that it may use POSTs?

Comment: I tried doing an ajax request to my non ajax handler and I see a print out I added, so it's no client side problem; I don't get it.